# Force NVCC not to consider constructors for constant memory

Tags: c++, constructor, cuda, nvcc

I am declaring an array of structure containing objects(myVector)  with constructors.

```
struct decoderdata{
  myVector<int> code; 
  myVector<int> sequence;
};
__constant__ decoderdata var[4];
```

myVector is my own class with constructor and destructor. I am using those constructors in my host code. I don't want to call constructors when I allocate constant memory. I will use cudaMemcpyToSymbol to initialize constant memory separately. All I want is, constant memory space with size of 4 'decoderdata objects' with type as decoderdata array.

when I compile, nvcc compiler creates
 **error: can't generate code for non empty constructors or destructors on device**.

I don't want nvcc to consider my constructors. How to supress/disable this particular error in NVCC?
or Is there any workaround in CUDA to achieve what i want?

Comment: That makes no sense. You can't have an object that hasn't been properly constructed. If you can't execute constructors, you can't have objects.

Comment: Have you defined a device constructor for `myVector`?. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the memory, without objects, then just do that:

```
__constant__ char data[4 * sizeof(decoderdata)];
```

You just have to be clear about the fact that you do not have any objects here, and you cannot treat raw memory as objects. And since the memory is constant, you cannot placement-new into it either. At best you can copy some trivially-copyable objects into it, but that seems unlikely (since something with a user-defined constructor isn't trivially copyable).

Comment: Is there any way to get this constant memory mapped to decoderdata[] type? (something like static_cast<> ?)

Comment: @lxkarthi: You can cast all you want, but it would just be undefined behaviour and your program would be a horrible, broken mess.

Comment: I am creating Array of structure to process multiple codes in single kernel. So, i can't pass it using kernel parameters(which is usually in constant memory). So i explicitly create constant memory to copy Array of structure. 
BTW, why would NVCC create an error for constructors in constant memory. A warning would be enough. Is there anyway i can suppress this error to get my executable?

Comment: @lxkarthi: you can't do it because (a) constant memory is, well, constant, so any attempt by device code to modify it is illegal, and (b) constant memory is statically defined and intialised at context establishment time, so there is no way that executable code can be run at object instantiation time (that is only permitted inside a running kernel). So what you want to do is illegal, and the compiler can't honour it, thus the error message.

Comment: @talonmies (b) I know that constants are established at context establishment & constructors will not be called. My doubt is 'why compiler shows it as error? They could have made it as warning, so that I can get my executable'. Many people will face problems in creating constant objects. If they remove all constructors, then in CPU objects, they have to call it init functions explicitly.